# Adding item to arraylist doesnt add it?

Tags: java

So basically I am making a small project for fun. I've made a Creature object, and in the Simulation class I've made a creatures list. The problem is that no matter how I access the list it will not add the item. it seems to completely ignore all the code that is written after the adding statement.

I've tried a getter. `Simulation.getCreatures.add(creature)`.
I've tried accessing it manually. `creatures.add(creature)`.
I've tried making an add method. `Simulation.addCreature(creature)`.
None of these works

This is a snippet of the main class. Yes i have put it in the main method, and the code before that works perfectly fine. It creates the creature just fine. But it ignores the addCreature and the print.

(sorry but i was unable to get the code format working. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with that too)

```
Creature creature = new Creature(420, 120, 120, 1);
Simulation.addCreature(creature);
System.out.println("yes");
```

This is a snippet of my simulation class. In the addCreature section it doesnt even print.

```
private static ArrayList<Creature> creatures = new ArrayList<>();
static void addCreature(Creature creature){
System.out.println("ADDED CREATURE");
creatures.add(creature);
}
```

There are no error messages. Thanks a lot in advance and I hope you can point out something that i did wrong.

In case you need the entire code: https://github.com/SearchForMe/Simulation

Comment: instead of making Simulation variables/functions static, have you thought about making them nonstatic, and keeping instances of each of them (like you did for the Creature Class)? Also, the reason you cant call it from outside is that you haven't declared the function as public

Comment: Be sure to read and understand the concept of static in java and how to properly use it

Comment: I changed the access modifiers to public in the Simulation class. Thank you very much for your suggestion. Could you please take another look to see if what I did was what you intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nexevis and Abhishek Patel already said, you should replace many of the "static" parameters/methods to non-static. That being said, that is not the reason for your problems with adding a new creature.

I downloaded your code from GitHub and added the following print outs to your main class:

```
    System.out.println("1");
    setDebugActive(false);
    System.out.println("2");
    frame = new Frame();
    System.out.println("3");
    Simulation.setSimulationState(true);
    System.out.println("4");
    System.out.println("5");
    Creature creature = new Creature(420, 120, 120, 1);
    System.out.println("6");
    Simulation.addCreature(creature);
    System.out.println("yes");
    System.out.println(Simulation.getCreatures().size());
```

I noticed that only 1-5 were printed out, and immediately after those print outs came multiple print outs such as:

```
Found food at: 63 32
New Position: 122 121
moved
```

From this I found that you are using a while loop inside of the constructor of your `Creature` class, thus the constructor never returns and the code never reaches the point where it adds to the ArrayList.

You should never have an infinite while loop in a constructor... never... Instead, I'd suggest using something such as the `Timer` class in order to schedule updates. I would have the Timer call an update function in Simulation, and then simulation calls an update function in each of the creatures in that function.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't check his full code.  @SearchForMe you should look up some best practices, there are a lot of things you do that may be _allowed_ but you really shouldn't do it.

Comment: good catch, i just skipped over that part. for future reference, if you have to do any computation in an init function, try to make it into a seperate function, and call that again after you have called your constructor

Comment: Thanks:) I agree with Nexevis completely, in many cases not following the best practices can lead to weird errors like this (I've once had an infinite while loop cause the system to lose network communication, something *seemingly* unrelated...)

Comment: Thank you so so so much for your suggestion. Now it manages to add it quite fine.  I have also updated the github code. But I've noticed an issue with the "AI". It seems to bug out and not move, or when it moves it shows new coordinates for a few moment and then it stops. I suspect it has to do with a negative number, but even after looking though it again I haven't been able to find an answer. Thanks a lot though for your answer.

Comment: It seems that you've made great changes in the right direction, but didn't 100% correctly implement the Timer. I can help you further on this if you want; if so, I'd suggest that we open a separate chat room to not flood this thread. What do you think?

Comment: Sure thats ok. Would discord be a viable option for you? Mine is SearchForMe#6671, but if you dont have it / prefer not to use it tell me! Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: I know this isnt the right place to do this, but i saw your message too late. Thank you so so much for helping me with this project

Comment: Happy to help:) As long as you had fun in Java and learned something new, I’m good.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nexevis said, you seem to be using static incorrectly in the `Simulation` class. In addition, every function that you need accessible from outside should have a modifier in front of it to set it as `public`. As per Java documentation,

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)

Comment: It does seem that he is using them all in the same package however.

Comment: that is true. @SearchForMe does `getCreatures().size()` return 0?